# Diagnosing HDD performance

Tags: linux, hard-drive, bad-sectors

I have a 2.5 inch HDD for that was bought new about a year ago and connected to a Raspberry Pi 4 to act as a NAS.

The HDD (a WD Blue WD10SPZX, 1TB, 5400rpm, SATA 3) is housed in an USB 2.0 aluminum case (I though it may help with cooling). Local network is all wired (except a laptop) using Gigabit CAT6 cable. The NAS throughput peaked at about 30MB/sec, both when reading and writing.

The entire system is housed in a box that is actively cooled, and I think that the airflow is enough to provide adequate cooling, as the PI CPU usually oscillates at about 50°C when idle and at 68-70°C when used at 100%.

Since March, this particular HDD seems to have developed a performance issue, which I can best describe as this: when large quantities of data is copied to the HDD, after about 15-20 GBs the transfer rate drops to around 3-4MB/s.

There are additional side effects to this, as not being able to SSH into the Pi while the transfer is in progress, and already established connections to the Pi being dropped.

### What I have found:

The partitions are aligned.

It did not ran out of inodes:

```
$ df -i .
Filesystem       Inodes IUsed    IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/sda3      59809792 13848 59795944    1% /mnt/media
```

`smartctl` seems to indicate that everything is in order ([complete output here](https://pastebin.com/qK4jmFaT)). That, or I don't know how to read the output. Partial output below:

```
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   200   200   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   194   193   021    Pre-fail  Always       -       1283
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       28
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   200   200   140    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   091   091   000    Old_age   Always       -       7161
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   100   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       21
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       18
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       24
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   095   093   000    Old_age   Always       -       48
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0008   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
```

`hdparm` also seems to indocate that everything is in order:

```
$ sudo hdparm -Tt /dev/sda3
/dev/sda3:
 Timing cached reads:   1708 MB in  2.00 seconds = 854.45 MB/sec
 Timing buffered disk reads:  92 MB in  3.04 seconds =  30.25 MB/sec
```

Problems appear only when doing write tests:

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=out.bin bs=1G count=5
5+0 records in
5+0 records out
5368709120 bytes (5.4 GB, 5.0 GiB) copied, 168.331 s, 31.9 MB/s

$ dd if=/dev/zero of=out.bin bs=1G count=15
15+0 records in
15+0 records out
16106127360 bytes (16 GB, 15 GiB) copied, 514.209 s, 31.3 MB/s

$ dd if=/dev/zero of=out.bin bs=1G count=40
40+0 records in
40+0 records out
42949672960 bytes (43 GB, 40 GiB) copied, 12551.7 s, 3.4 MB/s
```

All three tests were conducted in sequence, causing ~60GB of data to be written.

To summarize:

```
Data |  Time (s) | Time (h) | Write average
-----|-----------|----------|--------------
 5GB |   2.8 min |          |     31.8 MB/s
15GB |   8.5 min |          |     31.3 MB/s
40GB | 209.2 min |    3.5h  |      3.4 MB/s
```

I have not monitored the actual writing speed in real time during these write tests, so I cannot say if during the last 40GB test, the entire test ran at 3.4 MB/s, or if the test started at 30 MB/s and then dropped way below 3.4 MB/s in order to get to that average speed.

Since these tests read data directly from `/dev/zero`, this excludes any issues caused by the network.

*The only thing that I think I can do is to remove the drive from the aluminum case and check the performance again - assuming that the performance drops due to overheating.*

**My question is if there is anything else that I can do in order to determine a clear cause.**

Also, I'm considering returning and replacing the drive as it is still under warranty, but I'm not sure what the return reason could be and how can I demonstrate the bad performance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

Defragmentation can be an issue.
Try to trigger your erroneous behaviour on another freshly formatted drive.

Run the process from another linux machine to exclude the Pi being the culprit.

Use the drive without the alloy housing to exclude/verify thermal issues.

Comment: Writing speed starts always at ~30MB and drops after 15-20GB of data being written continuously, regardless of free disk space. I think this removes disk fragmentation as an issue. I have removed the aluminum enclosure, this caused the drive temperature to drop by about 10°C, however, it did not improved performance. I'll test the drive with another PC and SATA/USB adapter as soon as I can in order to eliminate a potential faulty adapter as a cause.